# Can't send complex json data to server using prototype and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, prototypejs

I'm trying to send the following data to the server but at the server side I don't see the json parameter that I'm sending. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Below you can see the code.

### Prototype:

```
send_data_url = "change"  

hash = $H({"blocks": [{"h": "2", "area": [{"width": "96%", "els": [{"title": "first", "mand": true}, {"title": "second", "mand": false}]}]}]});  

var request_array_json = hash.toJSON();  

new Ajax.Request(send_data_url, {  
  method: 'post',  
  parameters: request_array_json,  
  contentType: 'application/json;'  
});
```

### Rails:

```
def change()  
   debugger  
   my_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params["_json"])  
end
```

In the controller I see that the params object does not have the json parameter.
It only shows the action and the controller:

```
{"action"=>"change", "id"=>nil, "controller"=>"default/test"}
```

Note: I'm using prototype 1.6 qnd rails 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a plugin called [json_request](http://github.com/assaf/labnotes/tree/master/ruby/rails_plugins/json_request/).

To get this working nicely, I also wrapped Ajax.Request with a new class that can send complex JSON objects. Example code:

```
Ajax.JSON = Class.create(Ajax.Request, {
  initialize: function($super, url, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.contentType = ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded’;
    options.postBody = Object.toJSON(options.object);
    $super(url, options);
  }
});

new Ajax.JSON(url, { object: myObject });
```

Read more: http://labnotes.org/2007/12/11/json_request-handling-json-request-in-rails-20/comment-page-1/#comment-143190#ixzz0n5iKnO60